# Making a position: fixed element keep others at distance while scrolling

Tags: html, css, list, hover, transition

Good day! I have run into a problem with my list of items.

[image: Gif of problem occuring]

This is what happens with all of my items that are more than 1 line long. I use this CSS to achieve the effect:

```
.listas:hover{
    color:black;
    font-size: 20;
    text-decoration:none;
    transition: all .1s ease;
}
```

It seems to me like it is occuring when the mouse cursor appears in-between the lines which makes the `:hover` property stop working. Is there a way around this? Thank you for any kind of help :)

**EDIT: @Toby has helped me fix the issue.**

adding `display: inline-block;` in `.listas:hover{}` fixed my problem!

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the `line-height`? I think a large `line-height` causes the gaps between the broken lines.

Comment: Can we see your HTML?

Comment: The declaration `font-size: 20;` is not valid - it should include px, em, etc at the end: `font-size: 20px;`.

Comment: Oh, and for the inconsistent hovering, set `display: inline-block;`, I think that will do it.

Comment: @toby I fixed my font size to `20px`,  and set `display: inline-block;` and it fixed the issue. Thank you :)